# matlab mex: Access data

Tags: matlab, mex

Hey there,
I don't really understand how to access data passed via arguments in matlab to a mex-function. Assuming I have the 'default' gateway function

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
```

And now I get the pointer to the 1. input argument:

```
double* data_in;
data_in = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
```

Both the following lines EACH seperatly make my matlab crash:

```
mexPrintf("%d", *data_in);
mexPrintf("%d", data_in[1]);
```

But why can't I access the data like that when data_in obvisously is a pointer to the first argument?

1. When do I need to declare the pointer as double* and when as mxArray*? Sometimes I see something like that: mxArray *arr = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n,m,mxREAL);!?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data_in` is a pointer to `double` so you need something like

```
mexPrintf("%f", data_in[0]);
```

This assumes the caller passed a vector or matrix of size > 0.

More generally, you can

```
int n = mxGetN(array);
int m = mxGetM(array);
```

To get the number of rows and columns of the matrix/vector passed to the mex function.

### Regarding `mxArray`:

Matlab packs its matrices (complex and real) in an mxArray structure. `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` returns a pointer to such structure. To actually access that data you need to use mxGetPr() for the real part and mxGetPi() for the imaginary parts.

These return pointers to the allocated `double[]` arrays, which you can use to access (read and write) the elements of the matrix.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too, but when I use `mexPrintf("%f", data_in1[0]);` in my mexfile, it makes matlab crash...: "------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Thu Apr 28 11:45:00 2011
------------------------------------------------------------------------"

Comment: @bjoern: make sure the pointer returned from mxGetPr is not NULL (0) and that mxGetN and mxGetM return numbers >= 1

Comment: OKay thanks, now it works good! But I have one further question: Assuming I pass a matrix via myfunction([1:2; 3:4]) I wonder why I can't access the data like that (after `in = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);`): `mexPrintf("%f", in[0][0]);`, instead of this, I have to use a 'single'-indexing like that: in[3] will return 4 and in[0] will return 1. Why no more 'obvious' double-indexing like in[n][m]?

Comment: @bjoern: You can access an array in C using the x[row][column] notation only if the compiler knows the number of columns per row at compile time (so it can rewrite this as x[row*elelemnts_per_row + column]). Since the dimension of the Matlab array is not known beforehand, you cannot use the x[][] notation. If you are writing c++ you can wrap mx_array in a class and defile a suitable operator() so that you could access elements like x(row, col).

Comment: So this is really the behaviour as it is meant to be? :)

Comment: @nimrodm: So one need to access the data like that: mexPrintf("%f", *(in+i+j*m)); where i is loop index over the rows (i=0..m-1) and j is the loop index over the columns (j=0..n-1)? Seems a `weird` to me

Comment: Okay I found the answer: It's the correct offset, which is also described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order

Comment: extractsettings(dmd *d, const mxArray *p){    
    mwIndex j=1;
    const char *property;
    for(int i=0;i<=14;i++){
        property = mxGetFieldNameByNumber(p, i);
        mexPrintf("%s-- \n",property);
    }
    char *prop;
    prop = (char*)mxGetData(p);
    mexPrintf("\n%s\n",prop);    
}

I a matlab struct(p) passed with strings as its fields. I am able to access field names in the *for loop* but I am trying to access the properties and unable to do so. Plz can u tell where I may be going wrong.

My struct looks like
{
PRO_POLARITY : PRO_LEVEL_LOW
PRO_EDGE : PRO_EDGE_RISING
(15 elems)}

Answer (score 2):

A very convenient way of handling dimensions of mxArrays is to introduce a function like the following.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdarg>
#include "mex.h"

bool mxCheckDimensions(const mxArray* mx_array, size_t n_dim,...) {
    va_list ap;             /* varargs list traverser */

    size_t *dims;           /* dimension list */
    size_t i;
    size_t dim;
    bool retval = true;

    va_start(ap,n_dim);
    dims = (size_t *) malloc(n_dim*sizeof(size_t));

    for(i=0;i<n_dim;i++) {
        dims[i] = va_arg(ap,size_t);
        dim  = mxGetDimensions(mx_array)[i];
        if (dim != dims[i])
            retval = false;
    }

    va_end(ap);
    free(dims);

    return retval;
}
```

In this way you check an array mxArray* p is a double array of size say 1,3 using

```
double* pDouble = NULL;

if (mxIsDouble(p)) {
    if (mxCheckDimensions(p, 2, 1, 3)) {
        pDouble = (double*) GetData(p);
        // Do whatever
    }
}`
```